# Execute block after UIImage appears on screen

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView, and (ostensibly) after assigning the view a new image I am toggling the behavior of a button. My issue is that the buttons behavior is being toggled before the image actually appears on the screen. The following is an example of what I am looking at:

```
import UIKit

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var Image: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Touch: UIButton!

    var touchCounter : UInt8 = 0
    var touchStart : Bool = true
    var touchCount : Bool = false

    func start() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            self.Image.image = UIImage(named: "MyStartImage")
            self.touchCount = false
        }
    }

    func end() {
        self.Image.image = nil
    }

    @IBAction func screenTouch(_ sender: Any) {
        if self.touchCount == true {
            self.touchCounter += 1
        } else if touchStart == true {
            self.touchStart = false
            self.touchCount = true
            self.start()
        } else {
            self.end()
        }
    }
```

The issue is if I just button mash the screen I never actually see the image. Is there some method for executing a block of code after the image actually shows up on the screen? I am ideally looking for a solution that is very precise. This code in reality is being executed in a real time thread, and I am querying mach_absolute_time() between assigning the image view to my image and toggling the behavior of the button.

Comment: Can you describe what you did and what you observed? From what I can see, the user is supposed to tap the button as many times as they can in one second, before the image shows up? What part of it is not working?

Comment: The user's tap can call the end() function and set the ImageView to nil before the image assignment in the start() function is actually visible on screen. Essentially if I hit the button rapidly enough (or just arbitrary close to the 1 second mark) the image is never seen by the user.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in the implemented logic. You might want to do something like this

```
var loadingImage = false

func start() {
    loadingImage = true
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
        self.Image.image = UIImage(named: "MyStartImage")
        self.loadingImage = false
    }
}

func end() {
    if loadingImage == false {
        Image.image = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to just be moving the logic from the button action to within the function calls, this doesn’t actually change anything.

Comment: It can be used in either place. The point I was trying to get across is to set a flag before your start loading the image and disable it when the image is loaded. This way, you can use the flag to check whether to allow `end()` to run or not. Your current code doesn't implement this logic

Comment: touchCount is set to true and touchStart to false before calling start(). This sends touches to the touchCount block. When the image “finishes loading” touchCount is set to false. Now both are false so a touch is sent to the else block, calling end(). Except “finished loading” does not mean “visible on the screen” in this context since i can process a touch that calls end() without actually seeing the image. You moved touchCount = true from just before start() gets called to just after start() gets called, and I get the same behavior from running your variation of the code.

Comment: What's the size of the image?

Comment: It is tiny. A 500x500 pixel png that is a whopping 12KB. It seems that UIImage() returns immediately, but there may be a few frames before it is actually visible on screen. I am now attempting to:

1. cache the UIImage 
2. call setNeedsDisplay() on the view
3. Combine step 2 with a CADisplayLink to know the frame that the image is drawn

Comment: Maybe try running it through instruments?

Comment: Is this not the expected behavior? I am UIImage it does not hold onto the flow of control until it is actually rendered on screen, it just returns immediately. So I have some period that my button can nil out the imageview before the UIImage assignment actually results in an image on screen. If I just set a breakpoint on  ```self.loadingImage = false``` the image is not on screen when I come to that breakpoint.